# Aggregation and matching fields with an array in java mongodb

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
movies:{_id:"12",
      name:"comedy",
      rating:[{
        {user_id:"1",rate:5},
        {user_id:"2", rate:8}, 
        {user_id:"3",rate:4}
             }]
      }
```

I have an array of users[] in java that contains a set of users_ids. (users={"2","3"});
Also, I have a collection of movies that contains the rating of users to the movie.

I want find all movies that are rated by the users in the array and order them by the sum of these users'rate, recomended top3.

Comment: Your "rate" fields are strings which means the aggregation framework cannot sum them unless they are numeric values. It is also unclear whether your intention is to sum up all the ratings for all matched users or if you want to sum each user individually.

Comment: I have edited the rate field as not string. I want to sum up all the ratings for all matched users and then return the top three movies with the highest sum. for example: here it should sum the rating of the users 2 and 3 which is 8+4.

Answer (score 0):

I did some modification in your document like

{_id:"12",
      name:"comedy",
      rating:[
        {user_id:"1",rate:5},
        {user_id:"2", rate:8}, 
        {user_id:"3",rate:4}
             ]
      }

Try this

> db.movies.aggregate([{$unwind:"$rating"},{$group:{_id:"$_id",rating:{$sum:"$rating.rate"}}},{$sort
>   :{"rating":-1}}])